# function that delete duplicate row, sheet and google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to get a script that delete o duplicate row or cels.
follow next requiriement

| Id | Use | Color | Cant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40220761 | Pantalon | Rojo | 3 |
| 42863313 | Remera | Celeste | 2 |
| 39237132 | Camisa | Verde | 5 |
| 36712204 | Campera | Marron | 1 |
| 39952572 | Campera | Marron | 0 |
| 39952572 | Campera | Azul | 0 |
| 40877684 | Pantalon | Celeste | 2 |
| 39952572 | Camisa | Azul | 2 |
| 39952572 | Remera | Verde | 4 |
| 20335585 | Remera | Rojo | 2 |
| 38640205 | Pantalon | Verde | 3 |
| 40822540 | Medias | Verde | 4 |
| 36712204 | Pantalon | Violeta | 4 |
| 27596240 | Pantalon | Blanco | 4 |
| **36712204** | **Pantalon** | **Rojo** | 4 |
| 10318933 | Medias | Blanco | 4 |
| 25935061 | Medias | Azul | 4 |
| 10318933 | Pantalon | Azul | 1 |
| 10318933 | Remera | Blanco | 1 |
| 41363468 | Medias | Blanco | 1 |
| 12233157 | Camisa | Blanco | 0 |
| **10318933** | **Remera** | **Verde** | 2 |
| **27596240** | **Pantalon** | **Azul** | 3 |
| 36712204 | Pantalon | Rojo | 1 |
| 10318933 | Remera | Verde | 5 |
| 27596240 | Pantalon | Azul | 3 |

I need that script delete or clear cells duplicated,(color cels). I need compare ID; USE and Color columns nothing else....is not important cant.
I cant use ...data...remove duplicate of sheet menu or any plugin, cuz that just compare al row duplicated,

Comment: Please style your example table. And most importantly, post you code and tell the problem.

Comment: [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Adding as to what others have commented here, please provide a sample sheet showing a sample data and show what things have you done. Also, please review Dmitry's link for reference.

Comment: Probably you need just the Conditional Formatting for duplicated cells in column: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14728BosIVGshxXR6ZZGcLU-I5L1lYp9NbsQMYu1nfZI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need [Conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop), but if you want a script it's here:

```
function remove_duplicates() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().offset(1,0).getValues();

  // an object can have only unique keys
  // thus if we make key from a row content 
  // the object will have only unique rows

  const obj = {};
  data.forEach(x => obj[[x[0],x[1],x[2]].join()] = x);

  const new_data = Object.values(obj); // make an array from the object's values

  sheet.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(2,1,new_data.length,new_data[0].length).setValues(new_data);
}
```